# Android Bluetooth SPP Server

Tags: android, bluetooth, server, spp

I'm new in Android programming and i now have a problem.
I want to use my android phone as a bluetooth server, which means that when I open a special Activity the phone should listen to other Bluetooth devices (which are already paired) and the other device can open a conncection to my android phone. So it should be like the phone is a pheripheral device, like a bt speaker.
So the pairing is still done. And in found out that I have to use the SPP mode. When it's connect i want to send an receive simple byte streams.
I found a app called 'bluetooth spp tools pro' (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.dzs.android.BLE_SPP_PRO&hl=de) which does almost everything i want. But here the problem is that the phones works as client and opens the connection.

So maybe you could help me and give me some tips to understand what i have to do.

Thanks for the help:)

EDIT: Now I tried a Example from Android and It seems like it is almost working. I can connect my pc with the Smartphone and the smartphone connects with it. But when it has connected, the app crashes and I don't know why...
maybe you can tell me why ma app crashes.. here the code:

```
public class BluetoothServer extends AppCompatActivity {

public BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;

private TextView textViewStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth_server);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    textViewStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BluetoothServerTextView);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
    mSecureAcceptThread  = null;
}

public void onClickOpenBluetoothServer(View view) {

    // Setup Bluetooth Adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    //Enable Discoverbility
    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    textViewStatus.append("\nDiscoverable Added!");

    //Starting Accepting Thread
    mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
    mSecureAcceptThread.start();
}


/**
 * Accepting Thread mit run();
 */
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
            tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("PAKSAFE", MY_UUID_SECURE);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
        textViewStatus.append("\nAcceptThread Created!");
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                textViewStatus.append("\nListening");
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                //manageConnectedSocket(socket);
                textViewStatus.setText("Acccepted");
                try {
                    mmServerSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The original question has nothing to do with your updated question. Move the second questions to new question. Show what you have tried, provide more info. Asking a question here in SO in such a broad way is against the rules.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `RFCOMM` socket (which is also known as the Serial Port Profile (SPP)) and listen for incoming data.

Android has an [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket.html) for that purposes, use `BluetoothServerSocket` and listen to incoming data.

An example of `BluetoothServerSocket` usage can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676165/how-to-create-a-bluetooth-server-socket-in-android)